# css integration of custom select into website

Tags: css

I found this website, they sell full-roll flavoured rolling papers. Excellent merchandise.

I noticed a very nice styling on their < select > where you choose "Single pack", "Full Box" or "Half box". It is shadowed (which probably I will be able to do), but also a different color (green) on the right side, personalizing the select drop-down.

I'm digging through their CSS code, tried to modify in my site some of their code, but still no chance.

I found in the CSS inspector of Chrome the folling part (where the green part is done green)

```
::selection {
background: #CFC;
color: #000;
text-shadow: none;
}
```

Check it on the net, but they say this kind of pseudo-selector is not pursued, being in the phase of proposal and removed for future references.

Do anybody know how to do that via CSS ?

cheers

here's the link for their site

http://www.rollingpaperdepot.com/Juicy-Jays-Blackberry-Brandy-Rolls

Answer (score 0):

They are using the background images for that color .